# If $A$ is dense in $(M,d)$, show $(A,d)$, $(M,d)$ have the same completion (isometrically)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

The hint I was given is that: If $\hat{M}$ is the completion for $M$ then $A$ is dense in $\hat{M}$.

I’m not really sure where to start. I know what a completion is, that they exist, and that they are unique up to isometry. I also know that if $M$ is a metric space with a dense subset $D$ and $N$ is a complete space, then a uniformly continuous function $f:D\to N$ can be extended uniquely to a uniformly continuous function $F:M\to N$.

Comment: @KevinLong I’m not really sure where to start. I know what a completion is, that they exist, and that they are unique up to isometry. I also know that if M is a metric space with a dense subset D and N is a complete space, then a uniformly continuous function f:D->N can be extended uniquely to a uniformly continuous function F:M->N.

Answer (score 2):

Another hint: let $X$ be a complete metric space, and $A$ a subset of $X$.  Then the closure $\overline{A}$ of $A$ in $X$, together with the inclusion map $A \rightarrow \overline{A}$, is the completion of $A$.

Comment: Sorry can you explain what you mean by the “inclusion map?”

Comment: The inclusion map is the function $i: A \rightarrow \overline{A}$ given by $i(a) = a$.